# How to assign a data from $.get to a variable, or read the responseText

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got this dict in JS -

```
{
    ranges: {
        "year 2013": ["01/01/2013", "31/12/2013"]
    }
    opens: 'left',
    format: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
    separator: ' to ',
    startDate: START_DATE,
    endDate: END_DATE,
    minDate: '01/01/2005',
    maxDate: '31/12/2023',
}
```

Now I'd like ranges to be dynamic and not hard coded so I managed to pull data using this request:
`$.get("accyears", function(data){data})`
I obviously can't put the whole thing in a variable as it's an object.

Trying to set 'data' as a global variable won't help as it's not referable outside its scope.

I can only use it inside the scope for console log or alert.
How can I pull `data` out and assign it to my dict --> `ranges`
Tried even setting `ranges: data` inside the scope, but having $.get request inside is not working.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of wrong assumptions:

> I obviously can't put the whole thing in a variable as it's an object

Yes you can, it's very simple and you can access it as a associative array or with dot operator (`object.key`).

> global variable won't help as it's not referable outside its scope

This is also not true, you can set it to a global variable, but it might seem that it's not accessible because you're trying to use it before it's set. Note that async code, i.e. a `$.get`, will execute *long* (in term of computer speed) after next line after. That's why you pass it a callback function or use `.done` function, so you can handle the data after it was received.

It's hard to recommend how to solve your problem, but I'd suggest make a callback function that will handle your data after it's received.

An example:

```
$.get(..., function (data) {
   globalData = data;
})
// use globalData
```

This **won't work** because, as mentioned before, `$.get` is async and you'll try to use `globalData` before it was set.

How to do it with a callback function:

```
$.get(..., function(data) {
    // use data like you wanted to use globalData
});
```

Or similar functionally with a bit different syntax:

```
$.get(...).done(function(data) {
    // use data like you wanted to use globalData
});
```

If this doesn't work for you, there must be a problem with either getting the data off the server, or your logic when using the data.

Comment: The first assumption isn't wrong as it refers my specific issue of handling text in a dictionary structure. Therefor an `object` isn't be an option.
You cleared out the reason for missing a global var though, so thanks.

And again, using the data inside
`$.get(..., function(data) {
    // use data like you wanted to use globalData
}); `
is not an option since I'm trying to put the output string in a data structure which cannot have the request inside it..

Comment: What you call dictionary is actually an object in js and you could get your data as JSON (or parse it manually) and then use the properties like you wanted. You can access the properties with dot operator (`object.key`) or as an associative array (`object['key']`).

Comment: My data is actually a json data passed from the server. At the console under 'responseText' I can see it so it passes okay.
I know how to access the object attributes, what I'd like to know is **where** is my string inside the object?
Knowing this is asyncroneous process, is this even an option to use this data in a pre-loaded structure? I've heard of a way to give the data through a promise, which will be loaded after the `$.get` has finished..

Comment: You do know that it gets serialized to a string and you have to parse it back?

Comment: Yup. My current problem is getting this string